# ActiveX control without a form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, activex

We are required to use a 3rd party ActiveX control.

The only issue is, the layer in our software is a business layer and has no access to a window or form.  It also runs on separate threads (and should work from any thread) that are not STA.

Rather than breaking our separation of UI from business logic, we used this workaround to make it work:

```
Thread thread = new Thread((ThreadStart)
delegate
{
_myActiveX = new MyActiveXType();
_myActiveX.CreateControl();

//more initialize work

Application.Run();
});
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.IsBackground = true;
thread.Start();
```

Then anytime we need to reference the control, we call `_myActiveX.BeginInvoke()` or `Invoke()`.

On disposing of this class (exiting our app), we dispose the control and abort the thread.

My question is, are there any problems with this?   Is there a better way to handle this?

Is there a better built in way to work with an ActiveX control from within an unknown multi-threaded environment?  We are trying to write our class in a way that wraps the control but will work from any thread.

UPDATE: As an answer suggested, we really would rather use the standard COM object and not use a control at all.  Our issue with that was we would get the error "(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)" upon the first method or property we call on the COM object.  This is a pretty generic error that we don't get when using the ActiveX, any ideas?

UPDATE: Our ocx is "CX25.ocx", using tlbimp.exe we get CX25Lib.dll.  Using aximp.exe, we get AxCX25Lib.dll and CX25Lib.dll.  CX25Lib.dll does not work in either case.  AxCX25Lib.dll works.

Comment: The above code I mention is working.  Has anyone had to use an ActiveX control without a form?  Or has anyone had issues using the standard COM object, but noticed the ActiveX works?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'd suspect that the correct approach depends on wether or not you expect callbacks/events from the control as it would depend on a windows message pump to handle them.

Comment: Yes, the above code works.  We have been using it for over a year now without issue.  We also use it with multiple COM libraries.  We ended up wrapping it in a class, and implemented Invoke/BeginInvoke to interact with the control, which is required.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm assuming this is the proper way to go about this.

We've been using my code above in test environments for the past few weeks with no issues.

If anyone has to use an ActiveX without a form, I assume this is one way to do it.

Just make sure to call _yourActiveXControl.CreateControl() directly after your ActiveX object's constructor.  This simplified many issues we had originally.

Comment: Thanks for posting this information, it looks like it would be really useful for some people.  Just a data point though, I've got an ActiveX control myself that this didn't work for.  I had to put the thing on a form that I run in the separate thread (but never had to show the form at least).

Comment: Thanks - a note about this to other people, if you are starting a form from another form/window, you need to do this in order to make the active x control work properly. The active X RDP client wouldn't pop up the box for redirecting drives etc in my case and so it would just close the form. Putting `CreateControl()` after `BeginInit()` on the control solved this. You don't need to do this if you have the main form with this embedded.

Comment: @jonathanpeppers Can you please have a look at my answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52801093/create-windows-session-programmatically-from-console-or-windows-service/52801094#52801094) and see if you can help me use your method in this question?

Answer (score 4):

If you are calling the ActiveX control from a business layer, that means that it must be able to be used without a UI, e.g. just by calling its public methods. Why not just create an interop RCW for the ActiveX control class and call its methods directly?

Comment: Are you speaking of running tlbimp on the .ocx control?  We tried that and it would not work.  We would get "Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))" any time we tried it from a standard COM object.  The ActiveX control works for some reason.

Comment: Have you tried `aximp.exe` instead of `tlbimp.exe`? It creates two assemblies: a normal RCW one and a WinForms proxy one. You may be able to use the RCW assembly on its own in code. Disclaimer - I haven't tried this, just guessing based on my `tlbimp.exe` experience.

Comment: Are the methods you want to call on the actual UI control class, or on a separate helper class? If they are on the UI control class, then I would expect it to throw a runtime error if it was instantiated outside an ActiveX control host. However, I would expect a separate helper class to be able to instantiated anywhere.

Comment: To me it looks like both classes have identical methods (except the AX has methods from System.Windows.Forms.Control).  So I feel like we are not doing anything wrong.  It almost seems like there is something going on within their ocx that is making .Net unable to use it from outside the AX host.

Comment: Not what I meant, I'll re-phrase. Suppose the OCX exposes multiple classes, e.g. TheUIControlClass, AHelperClass, AHelperCollectionClass, etc. Does your calling code (a) actually need to instantiate an instance of TheUIControlClass to do its job, or (b) can it get away with just instantiating one of the helper classes? If the answer is (a), then you're out of luck because it will expect to be contained within a proper host like AxHost.

Comment: The ocx only exposes 1 class/interface (besides some internal stuff like Events, SinkHelper, etc.), and it would appear to me that it shouldn't require the AxHost to work, but for some reason it does.  We do not want or need the UI control for our situation, but have no idea what is going on internally with the ocx--it was written by a 3rd party.

Comment: OK. :-( Have you tried instantiating the AxHost in your business code directly without adding it to a Form.Controls collection?

Comment: That is what the above code does.  It starts a new thread with it's own message loop--this is the only way I know to make it work, but it looks like a hack.  My question was if this is the proper way to use an AxControl without a Form, or why I have to use a control in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

My solution is to create a hidden winform that host the activex control

Comment: My solution seems much more lightweight.  What do you gain by using an off-screen form?

Comment: I have a third-party program which expose an activex control, no easy way to control the program, i turn to activex control. actually, i tried your solution, it seems it works too. so i will take your solution.

Comment: This was the only solution for a control I was using, so thanks for posting it.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but I would recommend using the TPL in our modern era.

It's better to use the task parallel library instead of the old threading API because of the features around exception handling, cancellation, continuation, and returning results.

Here's an example:

```
using (var sta = new StaTaskScheduler(1))
{    
    var taskResult = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        var results = new List<ResultType>();

        using (var ax = new MyActiveXType())
        {
            // important to call this just after constructing ActiveX type
            ax.CreateControl();

            ax.SomeIterativeEvent += (s, e) => results.Add(e.SomeThing);

            // if applicable, you can tear down the message pump
            ax.SomeFinalEvent += (s, e) => Application.ExitThread();

            //more initialize work

            // start message pump
            Application.Run();

            return results;
        }
    }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, sta);

    return taskResult;
}
```

Some points:

1. [`StaTaskScheduler`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/07/9990421.aspx) is a type found in the [ParallelExtensionsExtras nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ParallelExtensionsExtras/). You'll need this to schedule tasks to execute in a Single Threaded Apartment.
2. I'm passing 1 to the constructor of `StaTaskScheduler` so that it only ever creates a single thread for me.
3. `Application.ExitThread()` is called to stop the message pump, which in turn allows execution to pass by `Application.Run()` so that some result can be returned to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

The `CreateControl()` method is from AxHost and requires `System.Windows.Forms` as a dependency.
If you want to use ActiveX without UI you can directly create COM object of ocx using native call.

```
   [DllImport("ole32.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
    public static extern object CoCreateInstance([In] ref Guid clsid,[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object punkOuter,int context, [In] ref Guid iid);


public object createComObject(){ 
    Guid IID_IUnknown = new Guid("{00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}");

    var gid = "{6bf52a52-394a-11d3-b153-00c04f79faa6}"; //your ocx guid
    var clsid = new Guid(gid);

    object yourOCX = CoCreateInstance(ref clsid, (object)null, 1, ref IID_IUnknown);
  return yourOCX ;
}
```

You can later cast the COM object to required interfaces

```
IOleObject iole = yourOCX as IOleObject;

IWMPCore iwmp =  yourOCX as IWMPCore;
```

I have created Windows Media Player ActiveX without UI or AxHost in C# over this [link](https://github.com/vinitsiriya/WMP-Remote-Control/blob/master/RemoteWindowsMediaPlayer/RemoteWindowMediaPlayer/RemotedWindowsMediaPlayer.cs). It might help someone trying to run ActiveX without UI.