# Use object from other thread

Tags: c#, activex

I need to use ActiveX object without form. I have found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531512/c-sharp-activex-control-without-a-form), write same code

```
public class C
{
    private AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting rdp;
    private Thread thread;

    public void B()
    {
        rdp.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            rdp.Connect();
        }));           
    }

    public void A()
    {
        thread = new Thread((ThreadStart)
            {
                rdp = new AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting();
                rdp.BeginInit();
                rdp.CreateControl();

                //more

                Application.Run();
            });

        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
    }
}
```

And in method B I have exception "InvokeEvent: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created". rdp.InvokeRequired always false; rdp.IsHandled is always false What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are doing. But I had this error before.

Assuming that `AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting` inherits `Control`, the following might help:

```
public void A()
{
    // ...

    rdp.CreateControl();
    rdp.CreateHandle(); // Create handle for Control.

    // ...

}
```

Also, according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.createhandle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),

> **Notes to Inheritors** 
>   When overriding CreateHandle in a derived class,
>   be sure to call the base class's CreateHandle method to ensure that
>   the handle is created.

So, if you own `AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting` better place `base.CreateHandle()` if you are overriding `CreateHandle`.

Comment: rdp.CreateHandle get Compilation error 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()' is inaccessible due to its protection level and base.CreateHandle get 'object' does not contain a definition for 'CreateHandle'

Comment: my bad. what is `AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting` exactly?

Comment: try placing `rdp.EndInit();` after `rdp.CreateControl();`

Comment: What does it inherit? It doesn't matter what it does. What matters is what it is. Can you show me the code?