# Events not firing from COM component when in Unit (Integration) Test

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, nunit, unmanaged

I have an unmanaged `DLL` which I'm trying to create a `.NET` wrapper library for but am getting different behavior when I try and run a `NUnit(v3)` test over it compared to if it is just run from a button click off a WinForm app.

Background: During startup of the DLL I call its `Connect()` method, which ultimately causes the DLL to make a TCP connection. When the TCP connection is established I then get notified by wiring up a handler to its "Connected" event.
Once connected I then call other commands on the DLL.

In a simple test Winforms app, I have 1 button which instantiates the "DLL" and then calls the `Connect()` method. When the thread completes, the app sits idle for about 2 seconds, and then the "connected" event handler fires as expected. The event does not return anything.

But because the `connect()` is an expensive operation, and because my library is destined for a larger application, I created a `ConnectAsync()` method in my library and made use of the [async and await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx) keywords, and a [AutoResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx).  The `ConnectAsync()` method returns an instance of the "instantiated" DLL after it gets notified that the TCP connection is up from the event.
A bit of refactoring to the test WinForms app, and it works as expected.

Next step was to make an integration test using NUnit. However when the `ConnectAsync()` method is called from an async test, I can see the TCP connection establish on the remote application, but the event handler never fires. A day's worth of testing, searching and trial and error could not turn up why the `ConnectAsync()` works perfect off a simple Winforms button but not from a UnitTest.

Here is the test code

```
[Test()]
public async Task Test1()
{
    var conn = await GetConnection();
    //assert some commands on the conn
}

private async Task<TCPConnector> GetConnection()
{   
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var mre = new AutoResetEvent(false);        
        var ctrl = new TCPConnector();
        ctrl.serverName = server;
        ctrl.serverPort = serverPort;
        ctrl.onConnected += () => { mre.Set(); };
        ctrl.Connect();
        mre.WaitOne();
        return ctrl;
    });
}
```

I know this is not strictly a question, but I'm stumped and looking for ideas to try. Or pointers as to what is different between a button click event and a NUnit test execution.

In case it means something to somebody, the dll I'm calling is an unmanaged ActveX

**Update1:**
If use MSTest it works! So it has something to do with NUnit's startup environment.

**Update2:**
Through investigations in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40202460/registration-free-activation-of-native-com-activex-component-from-net) post, I by chance replicated the same behaviour without any unit testing frameworks, but instead via reg free COM. So I'm now thinking it is something to do with how the COM is activated and consumed ?

**Resolution**
Finally found the answer.
Credit to Chris for his answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935768/c-sharp-wrapper-interface-error-e-nointerface) question. All I had to do was add a `<comInterfaceExternalProxyStub />` section to the manifest as outlined, and bingo

**UPDATE 4**

Ignore the last updates and the resolution. They contain misdirection and false positives, and some lack of understanding of my behalf as I worked through the whole world of COM, Regfree COM, Interop, and COM Events. The problem is still unresolved.

*The key issue remains that when the COM is run under the context of a unit test the COM events do not fire. When run in a plain .exe they work just fine*

Comment: provide more details about the test code

Comment: @OrdinaryOrange: I'd try it [using `TaskCompletionSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178(v=vs.110).aspx#EAP) instead of `Task.Run` with `AutoResetEvent`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Stephen. I refactored the code to use `TaskCompletionSource` as suggested but am getting the same result as before. I'm thinking it must be some difference between the startup environments.

Answer (score 1):

My guess, without knowing what exactly the unmanaged DLL is doing, is that it is  an single threaded apartment (STA) COM dll. In this threading model, COM interop will marshall all calls to the DLL to the thread that creates the object (which in your unit test is blocked waiting on the auto reset event, thus nothing happens).

The event pattern works in the Winforms app because the main UI thread is an STA thread (check the attribute on your main method) and it is pumping messages, so callbacks are allowed and locks are superseded by COM message pumping.

If this is the case, the only way to test the wrapper would be to create an STA thread, run a message pump on it, then pass a message to the thread to trigger the creation of the COM object and the connection (in other words, it's a huge pain). What's worse is that the object will behave this way in a client application as well, so unless you create an STA thread in your wrapper and marshall all calls to it, you will not be able to use it asynchronously.

Comment: Ha I was off testing just this, and then came back here too see your post. So I can answer straight away. No luck unfortunately. I wrapped the call in a STA thread (using an approach from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531512/activex-control-without-a-form)) but that had no effect. I did discover that if I run it in MSTest that it works perfectly. So it is something to do with NUnit.

Comment: Yeah even put the `Connect()` inside of the `Application.Idle` event to make sure. The `Connect()` would fire, and I could see the connection at the remote end, but alas the `onConnect` event still would not fire.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris mentioned, it's because specific of working with COM Interop objects in STA threads. It happens because interop objects created in STA thread could be accessed (also event call) only from that thread.
All you need is to wrap the creation of any COM Interop in a separate thread.
Something like that that:

```html
private async Task<TCPConnector> GetConnection()
{   
    return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var mre = new AutoResetEvent(false);        
            Create(mre);
            mre.WaitOne();
            return ctrl;
        });
}

private TCPConnector ctrl;
private void Create(AutoResetEvent mre) 
{    
    
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
    {
        ctrl = new TCPConnector();
        ctrl.serverName = server;
        ctrl.serverPort = serverPort;
        ctrl.onConnected += () => { mre.Set(); };
        ctrl.Connect();
    });
}
```