# Registration free activation of native COM (activex) component from .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows, com, activex

I have a native dll (which is an activex control) that I need use with my .NET application without having to register the dll in the registry.

I have read several in depth posts about registration free activation, some of the better ones are

[A lengthy one from Steve White and Leslie Muller](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx)

[This one from samuel jack](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2012/09/a-quick-guide-to-registration-free-com.html)

[And another from Mike Makarov](http://developex.com/blog/using-com-without-registration/)

and from what I can see it is possible. However several hours and hundreds of tests later I just cant get it to work. I've done a bit of PInvoking and even less with ActiveX controls in .NET in my career, so would appreciate any input from anyone whom might have kicked goals on this before.

So far I'm following Steves advice, in terms of building an application that works and then trying to formulate the winning manifest file syntax via repeatedly running the regsvr32 command to add and remove the unmanaged dll's from the registry. Just a bog simple .Net console application with about 10 lines of code...

One part that I am confused about is the interop. The native dll's I have are also accompanied with managed runtime callable wrappers (RCW's). In my .NET application I add reference to these RCW's and then can consume the respective classes and functionality provided for by the unmanaged dll's. I'm not PInvoking via `dllimport`.

In creating the manifest files I'm unsure if I need to worry about these RCW's and how they work in a registration free scenario, or even if if they need to be in the compiled output?

I've also tried several tools such as (OLE/COM object viewer, Mt.exe from the windows sdk, and regsvr42 from codeproject). But the manifest structure and necessary GUID's all vary between tools and posts.

Current status is that I receive a `InvalidCastException` *"Unable to cast COM object of type System.__ComObject to interface type MyFunkyDllLib.FunkyDllControl. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{some guid}' failed due to the following error: Library not registered.*

Can anyone confirm the correct syntax for the application and dll manifest files ? Online posts even vary on the name with some using sxs in the name....

**Update1:**
Whilst Joe's answer below did not work it did give me some better insights into reg free COM. In the properties of the Interop dll (the one that that is added to the project reference from the list of installed COM components on the dev machine) I changed the Isolated Property to True. This has the effect of making VS dump a copy of the COM dll (not the interop, it is embeded in the exe) to the bin\debug folder. VS also then creates a myapplication.exe.manifest.

In this manifest file is supposedly sufficent information for reg free com. I found other posts indicating success with this method but in my case I still ended up with the same `InvalidCastException`.

Reading over Samuel Jacks post again, I tried his method of creating both a manifest for the exe and the COM dll using the clsid information from the VStudio output manifest when `Isolated=true`. (I also deleted the `<file/>` section created by VS from the exe.manifest). After unregistering the COM from the registry I now have success ! The application starts and does not error.
Why this approach works and not the `Isolated=true` I have no idea because it is beyond my knowledge of manifests and assemblies.

However we are still not at the wizards castle yet Toto.

Now I'm back at the same issue I posted on [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39943244/nunit-async-await-and-an-unmanaged-dll) thread. However in this scenario unit tests are not involved. Just a plain console application with 10 lines of code. Works fine when in normal registered COM mode, but not in reg free mode.

Comment: I suppose that technically this question is now answered. So I'll put any discussion on the last issue in the other SO thread

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After many hours of trial and error I finally got a solution to how to successfully implement RegFree COM. 
Here is a full explanation incase it helps someone else.

1. I create a new .NET class library in VS
2. Right click references and select the COM components of interest. 
   (Note: for the COM to be visible in the list they must be registered
   on the development machine. This can be acheived by using the
   Regsvr32.exe tool included with windows. Calling "regsvr32
   mycomdll.dll" registers it in the windows registry)
3. Right click the COM reference, goto properties, and then set Isolated=True. This has the effect of causing VS to output a .manifest file supposedly containing all the registry details necessary for a consuming .exe to know what resources to load instead of querying the registry. However in my case it was incomplete. Calls to Interop methods would work, but events from the COM component would not. See step 5 for my solution)
4. Build the project. The .manifest should appear in the build output.
5. Open the manifest in notepad or similar. Within the `<assembly />` tag I needed to add a `<comInterfaceExternalProxyStub />` tag with appropriate `IID`, `tlbid` and `proxyStubClsid32` GUID elements. Elements of the manifest are documented [on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374219(v=vs.85).aspx). In my case the proxy/stub was `proxyStubClsid32="{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"/>` which is the built in windows proxy. The iid and tlbid I originally discovered via [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) whilst calling regsvr32. An easier and more reliable option I later discovered was to use a tool like [SxS manifest maker](http://www.mazecomputer.com/) as it added a second `<comInterfaceExternalProxyStub />` that I originally did not have.
6. Create an exe project in VS and reference the previously built library.
7. Build the exe project.
8. Run regsvr32 /u mycomdll.dll. To remove all registry associations.
9. Run the exe. In my case calls to and events from the COM component in the class library worked perfectly.

Caveats: I dont know why VS does not include the `<comInterfaceExternalProxyStub />` element automatically in the .manifest. At the time of writing the only way to automatically update the manifest was to add a post build Task in VS. In my case I copied the entire XML manifest into an XML in the class library project and then just overwrote the .manifest file in the build output.

Unit (integration) testing of the COM is inconsistent. Currently in my case calls to Interop methods work, but events do not. It has something to do with the fact that the Test Runner is not compiled with knowledge of the dependencies  and therefore such are not present in the activation context.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing a typelib declaration...but ignore that for now...  Instead, do the following...

After playing with this on and off for a while, I decided that the easiest way to do it is using MSBuild and a GenerateApplicationManifest task.  I've been using it with a unmanaged app, but I don't see why it would not work with a managed app.  I say "app" ... because my app is managed but I have both COM libraries and .NET assemblies with ComVisible classes in them.

From your description it sounds like you are dealing with having COM and don't have to worry about consuming .NET assemblies from COM.  You can google for MSBUILD and GenerateApplicationManifest to get an example MSBuild file.

So, I assume you will not need to populate the "Dependencies" attribute of the task.  You will need to populate the "IsolatedComReferences" attribute with a list of your COM DLLs.  They can be a simple semi-colon delimited list, but usually they are in "ItemGroup" declarations in the MSBuild project file.  The COM DLLs need to be registered at the time you generate the manifest.

As for your RCW, there is nothing special you need to do.  IMO, they don't need to be in the manifest.  .NET has a way of finding them as long as they are in the same directory as your app/DLLs.

If you use MSBuild, you won't have to generate manifests for your COM DLLs... They probably already have manifests already... Usually, the wizards automatically generate manifests and embed them.  The only manifest that will need the COM type information is the manifest you generate with MSBuild.

The whole point of the manifests used in this manner is to populate the manifest space with all the COM information that would be in the registry.

Comment: You are correct I'm calling an unmanaged COM from a managed app. I tried your suggestion but I could not get VS to build the app.exe. The build would run but no exe in the output. I came across some posts about just marking the interop reference `Isolated` property to true without needing to do any MSBuild stuff. Seemed to work in that the COM dll's now appear in the output dir and there is an app.exe.manifest there too. But unregistering the COM dll from the registry still produces the exact same error.